# The control of the gradient

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$u$ is a $C^1$ function defined on the unit ball $B=\{x \in \mathbb R^n~|~ |x|<1\}$ such that $u(0)=0$. We set $B^+=\{x \in B~|~ u(x)>0\}$. If $\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in B} \left| u(x) \right| = m$, then can we find a constant $c>0$ independent of $u$ such that $\mathop {\inf }\limits_{x \in {B^ + }} \left| {Du(x)} \right| \le cm$? More strongly, can we take $c$ to be $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $\lambda=\inf_{B^+}|Du|$; we may assume $\lambda>0$ for otherwise there is nothing to prove.

First, consider the case $|Du(0)|>0$. Pick a gradient curve of $u$ beginning at $0$, that is, a solution of the ODE $\dot x=Du(x)$. Such a curve exists by the Peano existence theorem for ODE, and it is contained in $B^+$, except for the starting point, until it exits $B$. It must exit $B$ because from 
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x(t))=|Du(x)|^2\ge  \lambda^2 \tag1$$ 
we have $u(x(t))\ge \lambda^2 t$, while  $u$ is bounded from above in $B$.

Let $T$ be the exit time. Integrating a more precise version of inequality (1),
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x(t))=|Du(x)|^2\ge \lambda\, |\dot x(t)| \tag2$$
from $0$ to $T$, we get $u(x(T-))\ge \lambda |x(T-)|=\lambda$. Since $u\le m$, we conclude that $\lambda\le m$. $\Box$

---

If $Du(0)=0$, there is no such $c$. For a counterexample, let $u(x)=f(|x|)$ where $f$ behaves like this:

[image: counterexample]

Comment: In the case $Du(0)=0$, it seems to me that the conclusion does not hold since we can take $u$ to be greater than $0$ only on a small neighborhood of $\partial B$.

Comment: @Hezudao I initially thought so too, but you'll have to make the transition from $0$ to $>0$ somewhere, and the gradient will be close to zero there. This is what my proof expresses; let me know if you see any gaps in it.

Comment: In your proof, it is not clear to me why $x_0 \in \partial B^+$.

Comment: @Hezudao You are right; I am going to fix the answer.